# React-boilerplate Package versioning mismatch error even though Package updated to required version

Tags: reactjs, postcss, react-boilerplate, react-toolbox

I am using react-boilerplate [3.5.0] and trying to install react-toolbox. After installation we are supposed to run command `npm run build:dll` and now it gives error =>

```
Building the Webpack DLL...
Your current PostCSS version is 5.2.18, but postcss-modules-scope uses 
6.0.17. Perhaps this is the source of the error below.
Hash: dc615358062d53518c9f
Version: webpack 3.5.5
Time: 24479ms
```

After that I have even installed the required version [6.0.17] of postcss but still it's giving this error. Here's the log file if it helps.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1f7qbz4pHCuZC9b6s8NqzZHpFAIMloqLZ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: delete node_module folder and again install postcss.

Comment: @javed it didn't solve the problem. OK what I think could be the problem is the latest npm (?) See I have new updated version of postcss in package.json, BUT still old vserion is being written every where in package-lock.json. Now this is a new concept and new problem that I'm facing , if indeed this is the problem.
**PS** https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/16866

Comment: can you provide your  package-json file. and do one thing remove postcss entry manually from package.json file after that delete node_module folder and then again install required dependency with flag  example npm install dependency --save

Comment: here's the file @javed 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Pa9ckeXReWqbAZXKSOVUs6XUPcHNrO8F/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone looking for an answer, it's been told that React boilerplate has no support for Postcss (for now).

But there is a tried and tested solution by julienben and you can find it on this thread https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate/issues/2142 .